# cannot subscript a value of type 'inout [AnyHashable: Any

Tags: swift

Sorry super noobie here trying to compile this and it's the last error I'm trying to fix.

```
 let optionalString0 = formatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(localNotification.userInfo!["pokemonId"]as! Int))

    if optionalString0 != nil {
        imagen.setImage(UIImage(named: optionalString0!))
```

Comment: Please provide more of the code in question and the full text of the error.

Comment: Please accept the answer, if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think error is due to this statement:

```
NSNumber(localNotification.userInfo!["pokemonId"]as! Int)
```

I tried this in playground to reproduce the error:

```
var dict = [1: "10", "t": 100] as [AnyHashable : Any]

func foo( paramDict: inout [AnyHashable : Any]) {


        print(NSNumber(paramDict["t"] as! Int)) //getting the same error on this line
}

foo(paramDict: &dict)
```

In above code I get the same error on `print` statement

I solved this problem by modifying the above code like this:

```
var dict = [1: "10", "t": 100] as [AnyHashable : Any]

func foo( paramDict: inout [AnyHashable : Any]) {

        if let number = paramDict["t"] as? NSNumber {
                print(number)
        }

}


foo(paramDict: &dict)
```

so in your case you modify your code like this:

```
if let number = localNotification.userInfo?["pokemonId"] as? NSNumber {
    let optionalString0 = formatter.string(from: number)

    if optionalString0 != nil {
        imagen.setImage(UIImage(named: optionalString0!))
    }

}
```

Note: You can modify above code like this: (Its not related to the error in question but just a different way to write the above code(may be better))

```
if let number = localNotification.userInfo?["pokemonId"] as? NSNumber, let optionalString0 = formatter.string(from: number) as? String {

        imagen.setImage(UIImage(named: optionalString0))

}
```

Comment: `if let number = localNotification.userInfo!["pokemonId"] as? NSNumber {` Will crash if userInfo is nil. why don't you just use optional chaining there?  `if let number = localNotification.userInfo?["pokemonId"] as? NSNumber {`

Comment: is it Swift 2 ? It looks like Swift 3. AnyHashable is only available in Swift 3. `formatter.string(from: aNSNumber)` or `formatter.string(for: anAny)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help and feedback!

this looks like it works for so far

if let number = localNotification.userInfo?["pokemonId"] as? NSNumber, let optionalString0 = formatter.string(from: number) as? String {

```
    imagen.setImage(UIImage(named: optionalString0))
```

}